# How to build a binary tree

Tags: java, linked-list

Does it work?
decided to switch 678 and 1789 in the inOrder array, and that put 1789 to the left of 678, and a 0 to the right of 678. In the code below

```
public static BinaryTreeNode buildTree(int inOrder[], int preOrder[], int 
preIndex )
{               
if (inOrder.length > 1)  
{
    int inIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inOrder.length; i++)
    {
        if (preOrder[preIndex] == inOrder[i])
        {
            inIndex = i ;
            break;                  
        }
    }

    if (inIndex > 0)
    {          
        BinaryTreeNode node = new BinaryTreeNode(inOrder[inIndex]);

        if (preIndex < preOrder.length - 1 )
        {
        node.setLeft(buildTree(leftArray(inOrder, inIndex), preOrder, preIndex + 1));
        node.setRight(buildTree(rightArray(inOrder, inIndex), preOrder, inIndex + 1));  
        }

        return node;
    }           
}       
return new BinaryTreeNode(inOrder[0]);
```

}

Comment: have you debugged? removeFrom what? what are you trying to remove something from? a list? what does the removeFrom method do? ....

Comment: You should show what class we are in - a derivative of `LinkedList`?

Comment: To create a method RemoveFrom that removes the element from location pos of the List. The must also return the element removed. That method must first ensure that pos is valid index. If the pos value is invalid the function should throw the InvalidIndexException.

Comment: Without the context of the complete class, we cannot help you.

Comment: @Joe as Tobias said: a (more) complete context is required. Also: don't put that information in a comment, add it to the question.

Comment: You're trying to morph the code of an `add`  method into the code of a `remove` method, aren't you?  Don't confuse yourself like that!   Removing a node from a list isn't a variation on adding, it's an entirely different thing.  Just write a proper `remove`method from the ground up, starting with the proper method signature of `public T removeFrom(int pos)`

Comment: Of course it will add a node, you are creating a new node and put it on the `current.nextNode` variable with the value received. Why do you have a `T value` in that method by the way ? What you need to do is set `current.nextNode` value into the `previous.nextNode` value

Answer (score 0):

This code is to add a `Node`. You are creating a new node with the actual `nextNode` and set it into the `current.nextNode` value. This is adding a node.

```
 Node<T> current = firstNode;
 for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++)
      current = current.nextNode;
 Node<T> temp = new Node<T>(value, current.nextNode);
current.nextNode = temp;
```

What you need to remove a node, say the current selected by that loop, is to set the `current.nextNode` reference into the `previous.nextNode` value.

Something like : (untested algorithm)

```
if(pos == 0) head = null;
else {
     Node<T> previous = head;
     Node<T> current = head.nextNode;
     for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++){
         previous = current;
         current = current.nextNode;    
     }
     previous.nextNode = current.nextNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for removeFrom method should look likethis :

```
public int removeFrom(int value,int pos) {
        boolean exists = false;
        if(0 < pos && pos <= this.size){

        Node current = start.next;
        Node previous = start;
        Node deleted =null;
        for(; current!=null; current=current.next) {
            if(current.value == value) {
                 deleted = current;
                previous.next = current.next;
                current = previous;
                size--;
                exists = true;
                return deleted.value;
            } else {
                previous = previous.next;
            }
        }
        if(!exists)
            System.out.println("the value not exist");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("not valid position");

        return -1;
    }
```

As you can see in the example above i'm returning the value and not the Node but you can modify it , to don't lose the node, i'm putting the node i'm deleting in a tmp node variable . If you insert not acceptable values or positions it will print to you a console message , with the boolean variable i am able to know if it exists or not.